# How can i fill and texture a cylinder in java without using opengl or directx

Tags: java, texture-mapping

> is there a book or tutorial that show this with simple example?

Comment: What kind of technology/framework are you using for rendering the cylinder?

Comment: If you don't use OpenGL or DirectX to do it, I can guarantee you, it will not be a *simple* example.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is doable.

***Java:*** In standard java one could use BufferedImage, with its getGraphics method yielding a Graphics2D object. And then there are `ImageFilter`s.

***For the (non-perspective) math:***
If one looks straight at a cylinder one sees a width `2*r`, which actually is a half-circle `pi*r`.

```
actual coordinate:  alpha*r, between -0.5*pi*r and +0.5*pi*r
screen coordinate:  sin(alpha)*r, between -r and +r
```

Scaled:

```
screen[x, y] = image[asin(x), y]
```

On scaling one might interpolate some pixels, taking the average of

```
image[asin(x-1)+1, y] .. image[asin(x+1)-1, y]
```